# AWS seems to start another EC2 instance with same AMI automatically after termination

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, terminate

I have 6 ec2 instances and I want to terminate about 3 of them. I've tried terminating them from the command line using ec2-terminate-instances and also using the AWS mananagement console ( Right click on  instance and click on terminate).

The instance stops and goes into terminated state. However after some time another instance is automatically started with the same image of the terminated instance. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: is it possible that you have [autoscaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to stop instances and then terminate them separately it seemed to workw fine